# Pandas, fill values with dict keys based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
            Item  Weight  Bags    Must  quantity  must quantity  bags column length   assigned bag
0     planes bag    8.50  planes   v       1              1          6                  None
1  Full Bandolera   3.76  planes   v       3              2          6                  None
2  tail             0.30  planes   0       3              2          6                  None
3  central wing     1.08  planes   0       3              2          6                  None
4  engine           0.44  planes   0       3              2          6                  None
5  height steer     0.12  planes   0       3              2          6                  None
6  dihedral         0.40  planes   0       3              2          6                  None   
7  pods bag         8.72  pods     v       1              1          4                  None
8  Pod              1.74  pods     v       3              2          4                  None
9  optic            0.86  pods     v       2              2          4                  None
```

I need to assign a string to assigned bag from the following dict's keys:

```
bags = {'planes bag': 6,
        'pods bag': 4,
        'ground system bag': 13}
```

So far I have a function that filters out the rows that meet my condition to fill by:

```py
bags_lens = list(bags.values())
        df['assigned bag'] =  df[(df['Must'] != 0) & (df['bags column length'].isin(bags_lens))]
        print(df)
```

This function checks if must is checked and if the length of the bags column matches any of the values in bags dict.

if a row matches both conditions I need it to be assigned to the assigned bag column.

Meaning, for example, the rows planes bag and full Bandolera should assign the word 'planes bag'
to the assigned bag column.

To clarify my desired outcome.
If it was possible, I would something like this:

```py
df['assigned bag'] =df['Bags'] if df[(df['Must'] != 0) & (df['bags column length'].isin(bags_lens))]
```

Comment: what are the objects inside your dict, variables?

Comment: @Datanovice will edit

Comment: from what I see you are trying to assign a value to the column 'assigned bag' based on the length provided in column 'bags column length': 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

    df['assigned bag'] = df['bags column length'].map(bags = {6: 'planes bag',
        4: 'pods bag',
        13: 'ground system bag'}

Comment: @emiljoj probably needs to do some filtering first before mapping any values, try combining it with `.loc` or `np.where` and post it as an answer. you could use `np.select` too if you're brave =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do is to [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the `bags column length` to this dictionary:

```py
bags_inv = {
    6: 'planes bag',
    4: 'pods bag',
    13: 'ground system bag'
}
```

But, only on the condition that `Must` does not equal `'0'` (string!):

```py
df['assigned_bag'] = df.loc[df['Must'] != '0', 'bags column length'].map(bags_inv)
```

```py
0    planes_bag
1    planes_bag
7      pods_bag
8      pods_bag
9      pods_bag
Name: bags_column_length, dtype: object
```